# Does Filevault 2 encrypt deleted files created before Filevault activation?

Tags: macos, secure-erase, filevault

I have a 2013 Macbook Air that I'm returning (drive is SSD).  I didn't have Filevault turned on, and I erased the disk and reinstalled the OS (secure erase was not available as an option).  I then read that I could turn on Filevault 2 for extra security.  But if I do turn on Filevault 2, will it encrypt deleted files that were created before Filevault 2 was activated?